# How to change values of range in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change value of range (Source) and paste to to another range (destination) in excel vba. Please note that forward slashes may vary in source.

For instance I want to do like this but from vba excel:
[image]

**psedu code:**

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(A1,A4).Value = Replace source string before last forward with variable.

variable = "C:Destination\"

Basically I am amending values of Source and want to paste in destination.

**This Code works but paste same values from source to destination**

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(A1,A4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(B1,B4).Value

Please help in am new to VBA, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could achieve what you are trying to do, unless I am misunderstanding the question.

Could improve further by doing a count on range of populated cells in first column and setting it as the loop max iteration.

```
Dim Str As String
Dim Source As String
Dim Destination As String
Dim populated As Integer

Source = "C:\Source\"
Destination = "D:\Destination\"

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To N
    Str = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(Str, Source, Destination)
Next i
```

Comment: Destination (ColB) is not changing.Also if there is header then what will be the changes in code?lastly in my case source = 'cell list in colA' please help with code.

Comment: If there is a header, then start the loop count from 2, instead of 1. I've only Declared the Destination as a variable in case it does change at some stage. You could instead hard code it in the Replace function, instead of passing Destination variable in.

Comment: thanks but code have issue replace function doesn't work if I set destination or source to path (C:\Source\) but it works if I hard code string in place of source or destination like: Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(Str, "Source", "Destination")

Comment: Replace takes those arguments as a string. So to hardcore those paths, you would need Replace(Str, "C:\Source", "D:\Destination")

Comment: ok that make sense.how can I count on range of populated cells?

Comment: Please see amended code above. Finding value of N and using that instead of a hard coded max counter.

Comment: my excel sheet has header as well Finding value of N will take header into account as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here a simple example for increase and decrease cell values by 1 in a range:

```
Option Explicit

Dim actualRange     As Range
Dim cellRange       As Range


Public Sub increaseNumber()

    Set actualRange = Selection

    For Each cellRange In actualRange.Cells
        cellRange.value = cellRange.value + 1
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub decreaseNumber()

    Set actualRange = Selection

    For Each cellRange In actualRange.Cells
        cellRange.value = cellRange.value - 1
    Next

End Sub
```